# Integer values of polynomial $a^2+ab-b^2$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Playing with the polynomial $f(a,b)=a^2+ab-b^2=d$ for a given $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ I found that it has integer solutions $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for the following values of $d$: $$D'=\{1,5,11,19,29,31,41,55,59,61,71,79,89,95,\ldots, 209, \ldots\}$$
and also for every $d = k^2\cdot e$, $e \in D'$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So let $$D := \{d \in \mathbb{N} : f(a,b)=d \text{ has a solution}\}$$ I noticed that $D'$ contains many primes, but $55, 95$ and $209$ are not prime, but they are product of numbers in $D'$. So this lead to my

**Conjecture**: $D$ is multiplicatively closed.

I couldn't proove it so far, but this conjecture seemed so clean and simple to me that I thought someone must have discovered it before. So is there any theorem in this direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left(a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left( a + b \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) = a^2 + ab - b^2$$

Your polynomial is the norm on the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$, and hence the set of values of the norm is multiplicatively closed.

Answer (score 4):

A supplement, which I hope may be useful to OP, to Daniel Fischer's solution.

Let $x^{2} + s x + t \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ have the two non-rational roots $\alpha, \beta $, so that $\alpha + \beta = -s$ and $\alpha \beta = t$.

Then the norm of an element $a + b \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is
$$
(a + b \alpha) (a + b \beta) = a^{2} + ab(\alpha+\beta) + b^{2} \alpha \beta = a^{2} - ab s + b^{2} t. 
$$

So in this case $s = -1 = t$, and the roots of $x^{2} - x - 1$ are indeed
$$
\frac{1 \pm{\sqrt{5}}}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$a^2+ab-b^2=\frac{(2a+b)^2-5b^2}4$$

Now use the generalized form of [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity)

$$(A^2+nB^2)(C^2+nD^2)=(AC\pm nBD)^2+n(AD\mp BC)^2$$

Here $n=-5$